# Check Whether my Plot of Bounded Region and Its Revolution toward x-axis and toward y-axis are correct

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have tried this code to be able to plot a bounded region, between y=6x and y= 6x^{2}

Please check whether it is correct or not...

1. I want the bounded region to be revolved around x axis and y axis, become solid of revolution.
2. I want to add a legend so people will know the blue line is y=6x and the orange line is y=6x^{2}

this is my MWE:

```
# Compare the plot at xy axis with the solid of revolution toward x and y axis
# For region bounded by the line y = 6x and y = 6x^2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 100

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224, projection='3d')

y = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
x1 = (y/6) 
x2 = (y/6) ** (1/2)
t = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 2, n)

u = np.linspace(-1, 2, 60)
v = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 60)
U, V = np.meshgrid(u, v)

X = U
Y1 = (6*U**2)*np.cos(V)
Z1 = (6*U**2)*np.sin(V)

Y2 = (6*U)*np.cos(V)
Z2 = (6*U)*np.sin(V)

Y3 = ((1/6)*U**(1/2))*np.cos(V)
Z3 = ((1/6)*U**(1/2))*np.sin(V)

Y4 = (U/6)*np.cos(V)
Z4 = (U/6)*np.sin(V)

xn = np.outer(x1, np.cos(t))
yn = np.outer(x1, np.sin(t))
zn = np.zeros_like(xn)
for i in range(len(x1)):
    zn[i:i + 1, :] = np.full_like(zn[0, :], y[i])

ax1.plot(x1, y, x2, y)
ax1.set_title("$f(x)$")
ax2.plot_surface(X, Y3, Z3, alpha=0.3, color='red', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax2.plot_surface(X, Y4, Z4, alpha=0.3, color='blue', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax2.set_title("$f(x)$: Revolution around $y$")

# find the inverse of the function
x_inverse = y
y1_inverse = np.power(x_inverse, 1)
y2_inverse = np.power(x_inverse, 1 / 2)

ax3.plot(x_inverse, y1_inverse, x_inverse, y2_inverse)
ax3.set_title("Inverse of $f(x)$")


ax4.plot_surface(X, Y1, Z1, alpha=0.3, color='red', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax4.plot_surface(X, Y2, Z2, alpha=0.3, color='blue', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax4.set_title("$f(x)$: Revolution around $x$")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The blue line in your bottom left figure is `y = x` instead of the inverse of `y = 6x`...**

**I changed it to `y = 1/6x`.**

Plotting the revolution of the bounded region can be done by limiting the `np.linspace` of the `y`, `u`, and `x_inverse` values in your code. You can determine the limits by finding the intersection points of the two functions.

In the upper left plot, they intersect at `(0, 0)` and `(1, 6)`.

In the bottom left plot, they intersect at `(0, 0)` and `(6, 1)`.

The legends are also added. See the complete code below.

##### What I changed:

```
n = 200
y = np.linspace(0, 6, n)
u = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
v = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n)
x_inverse = np.linspace(0, 6, n)
y1_inverse = np.power(x_inverse/6, 1)
y2_inverse = np.power(x_inverse/6, 1 / 2)
```

[image]

##### Complete code:

```
# Compare the plot at xy axis with the solid of revolution toward x and y axis
# For region bounded by the line y = 6x and y = 6x^2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 200

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224, projection='3d')

y = np.linspace(0, 6, n)
x1 = (y / 6)
x2 = (y / 6) ** (1 / 2)
t = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 2, n)

u = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
v = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n)
U, V = np.meshgrid(u, v)

X = U
Y1 = (6 * U ** 2) * np.cos(V)
Z1 = (6 * U ** 2) * np.sin(V)

Y2 = (6 * U) * np.cos(V)
Z2 = (6 * U) * np.sin(V)

Y3 = ((1 / 6) * U ** (1 / 2)) * np.cos(V)
Z3 = ((1 / 6) * U ** (1 / 2)) * np.sin(V)

Y4 = (U / 6) * np.cos(V)
Z4 = (U / 6) * np.sin(V)

xn = np.outer(x1, np.cos(t))
yn = np.outer(x1, np.sin(t))
zn = np.zeros_like(xn)
for i in range(len(x1)):
    zn[i:i + 1, :] = np.full_like(zn[0, :], y[i])

ax1.plot(x1, y, label='$y=6x$')
ax1.plot(x2, y, label='$y=6x^{2}$')
ax1.legend()

ax1.set_title('$y=6x$ and $y=6x^{2}$')
ax2.plot_surface(X, Y3, Z3, alpha=0.3, color='red', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax2.plot_surface(X, Y4, Z4, alpha=0.3, color='blue', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax2.set_title("$f(x)$: Revolution around $y$")

# find the inverse of the function
x_inverse = np.linspace(0, 6, n)
y1_inverse = np.power(x_inverse/6, 1)
y2_inverse = np.power(x_inverse/6, 1 / 2)

ax3.plot(x_inverse, y1_inverse, label='Inverse of $y=6x$')
ax3.plot(x_inverse, y2_inverse, label='Inverse of $y=6x^{2}$')
ax3.set_title('Inverse of $y=6x$ and Inverse of $y=6x^{2}$')
ax3.legend()


ax4.plot_surface(X, Y1, Z1, alpha=0.3, color='red', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax4.plot_surface(X, Y2, Z2, alpha=0.3, color='blue', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax4.set_title("$f(x)$: Revolution around $x$")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Exactly. Good job. Voted